# SQLite. Updating value of primary key in specific order

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, sql-update, primary-key, between

I have the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE dataTable(
    ParentID INTEGER,
    MyIndex INTEGER,
    // other stuff
    PRIMARY KEY (ParentID, MyIndex )
);
```

Trying to decrease the value of "MyIndex" column for values that are in specific range.
For that purpose I think to have following statement:

```
UPDATE dataTable 
SET MyIndex = (MyIndex - ?)
WHERE ((ParentID = ?) AND (MyIndex BETWEEN ? AND ?))
```

Though i think that this could bring to a problem if the items with higher "MyIndex" value are decreased first which could have overlap with the ones that are not yet decreased. So for example if the values are (5, 4, 3) and are decreased by 1, when 5 becomes 4 there could be a primary key violation. but if the values are modified in 3,4,5 order that would not be a problem.

So I was trying to use the following statement instead:

```
UPDATE dataTable 
SET MyIndex = (MyIndex - ?)
WHERE ((ParentID = ?) AND (MyIndex BETWEEN ? AND ?)) 
ORDER BY MyIndex ASC
```

But I'm getting this error: "near "ORDER": syntax error". What is wrong with the ORDER BY?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first query will work fine, as constraint integrity isn't enforced until the end of the update..  ORDER BY is not supported in UPDATE statements.